# Can't upload image using codeigniter's upload() function

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, file-upload

I have created a pages controller, which call a view to upload an image. The pages controller is as follows:
Pages controller:

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends MY_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('pages_model');
    }
    public function index(){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('admin');   
        }
        else{
        $data[] = '';
        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('Admin_views/Index_views/pages_view');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
        }
    }
    public function create_page(){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('admin');   
        }
        else{
        $data[] = '';
        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('Admin_views/Page_views/create_page_view');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
}
    }
    public function insert_page(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('page_name','Page Name','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('page_desc','Page Description','trim');
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 2048000;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){
            $errors = array(
                'errors'=>  validation_errors(),

            );
            $this->session->flashdata($errors);
            redirect('admin/pages/create_page');
        }
        else{
            $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
             $data = $this->upload->data();
             $insert_data = array(
                 'page_topic'=>  $this->input->post('page_name'),
                 'page_desc'=>  $this->input->post('page_desc'),
                 'image_url'=> $data['full_path']
             );
             $result = $this->pages_model->insert_page($insert_data);
             if(!$result){

             }
             else{
                 redirect('admin/pages');  
             }
        }
    }
}
```

My view is as follows :

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3>Add New</h3>    
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php 
            $attributes = array(
                'class'=>'form-group',
                'name'=>'create_page'
            );
            echo form_open_multipart('admin/pages/insert_page',$attributes);?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_label('New Page Name');?>
                <?php $data = array(
                    'class'=>'form-control',
                    'name'=>'page_name',
                    'placeholder'=>'Enter Page Name'
                );
                echo form_input($data);
                ?></div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo form_label('Enter Page Description');?></div>
                <?php $data = array(
                    'class'=>'form-control',
                    'id'=>'mytextarea',
                    'name'=>'page_desc'
                );
                echo form_textarea($data);
                ?>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo form_label('Upload An Image');?></div>
            <div style="position:relative;">
        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
        <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>

                <?php echo form_close();?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">

</div>
```

After doing all this the other data as page name and description are being uploaded into the database, but neither the image in uploaded the uploads folder, nor the image url is being uploaded in the database. ANd i am not even getting an error.

By the way, i am developing this application on windows platform, using wamp server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code this how you will get error

```
public function insert_page(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('page_name','Page Name','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('page_desc','Page Description','trim');
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 2048000;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){
        $errors = array(
            'errors'=>  validation_errors(),

        );
        $this->session->flashdata($errors);
        redirect('admin/pages/create_page');
    }
    else{
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("userfile"))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($error);
        }
        else
        {
         $data = $this->upload->data();
         $insert_data = array(
             'page_topic'=>  $this->input->post('page_name'),
             'page_desc'=>  $this->input->post('page_desc'),
             'image_url'=> $data['full_path']
         );
         $result = $this->pages_model->insert_page($insert_data);
         if(!$result){

         }
         else{
             redirect('admin/pages');  
         }
    }
   }
}
```